# python - How to plot a bar graph with Pandas, using a group by from another country

Tags: python

I have a table with the following structure:

| Country | Status |
| --- | --- |
| UK | Churned |
| US | Active |
| France | Active |
| France | Active |
| US | Churned |
| UK | Active |
| US | Active |
| US | Churned |

And I would like a graph that shows a different bar for each country and then the bar value to be the amount of times a customer churned in that country
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQwZP.png)

if possible I'd also like to name the x and y axis.

So far I've been able to graph just the status by itself with:
`df['status'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')` but can't figure out how to group it by country.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to group by `Country` and `Status` and then get the count of `Status` per `Country`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's countplot will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.countplot(data=df, x='Country', hue='Status')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with the native pandas DataFrame visual integration, but I can demonstrate this with a combination of aggregation and seaborn.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['UK', 'US', 'France', 'France', 'US', 'UK', 'US', 'US'],
                   'Status': ['Churned', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Churned', 'Active', 'Active', 'Churned']})


# Group by country and status and get the unique count
agg_df = df.groupby(['Country', 'Status'], as_index=False).agg(count=('Country', 'count'))

# plot it
sns.barplot(x='Country', y='count', data=agg_df, hue='Status')
plt.show()
```